# How to make form input green when validation passed - NextJS, zod

Tags: next.js, zod, radix-ui

I'm using `Form` component from `shadcn` (https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/form) and I'm wondering how can I style the input depending on the validation results. Currently when it fails, red text appears below the input and when it passes the text disappears and the input is again normal. I'd like to make it green when validation passes, i.e. add custom class to style it. How can I do that?

Comment: https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/getfieldstate

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with the below code. Focus on the `Controller` component and the `className` prop

```
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form"
```

```
    const {
    control,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",

    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "",
    },
  });
 
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="firstName"
        rules={{
          required: true,
        }}
        render={({ field, fieldState }) => (
          <Input
            {...field}
            type="text"
            className={cn(
              !fieldState.error && !fieldState.invalid && fieldState.isDirty
                ? "outline-green-300"
                : fieldState.error
                ? "outline-orange-600"
                : "outline-amber-100",
              "text-black "
            )}
            placeholder="First name"
            value={field.value}
            tabIndex={1}
          />
        )}
      />
```